Why do we call Laplace transform linear?
As per my current understanding, a linear function/operation is a mapping that satisfies:
$$ L\{f+g\} = L\{f\} + L\{g\} $$
$$ L\{kf\} = kL\{f\} $$
for all inputs it could accept. At first glance, it seems like the above should hold for laplace transforms, because of how integration works. But then I learned from my textbook that, when you linearly combine laplace transforms, the ROC of the new transform might be larger than the union of the original ROCs. Eg, say $ f(t) = e^{-2t}u(t) $ and $ g(t) = -e^{-2t}u(t) $, then,
$$ \mathcal{L}\{f\} = \frac{1}{s+2}, Re\{s\}>-2 $$
$$ \mathcal{L}\{g\} = -\frac{1}{s+2}, Re\{s\}>-2 $$
Adding these, I think I'd get,
$$ \mathcal{L}\{f\} + \mathcal{L}\{g\} = 0, Re\{s\}>-2 $$
While $$\mathcal{L}\{f+g\} = \mathcal{L}\{0\} = 0, \text{for all s}$$ These results seem to be different mathematically because of the different domains, isnt this a violation of superposition? How can they be equivalent if their domains are different?
Edit: Is there a reconciliation that doesn't involve functional analysis? I haven't studied functional analysis.

It is a general feature of linear algebra  of unbounded operators.
In the worst case two operators may not have a dense common domain, but their sum can be extended to a dense domain.
Density in a certain subspace is crucial for series expansion to work.
Laplace transforms and Fourier transforms are designed to work on linear differential operators of any order to yield  rational functions in the image space. An k-th differential multiplies by $x^k$ under Laplace transform, severely shrinking the domain in a normed space.
Each application needs careful maximal extension of domains, the same  for the inverses. Together they define the maximal domain of the differential operator.
Thats 'Functional Analysis of Operators', vol 4 of Reed/Simon e.g.

Is an answer not possible without (functional analysis?). Why do they tell us about the linearity of Laplace transform? Seems like why its linear is beyond the scope of introductory books/courses

@Yeslin: one way to say it is that the difference in domain is not that important in some contexts and it makes sense to ignore it. In your examples the Laplace transform is meromorphic so the domain really doesn't matter because we can just do analytic continuation.
